how to fix error Error: Undefined name 'REG_SAM_FLAGS'. readOnly(REG_SAM_FLAGS.KEY_READ), in flutter ,
am getting this error message when i try to run my flutter app am not aware at all what causes it .. here is my pubspec.yaml
name: hakeeem
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.11+12

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: 3.0.0
  badges: 2.0.2
  cached_network_image: 3.3.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  cloud_firestore: 4.15.7
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 6.1.8
  cloud_firestore_web: 3.10.7
  cloud_functions: 4.6.7
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.5.18
  cloud_functions_web: 4.7.1
  collection: 1.18.0
  country_picker: ^2.0.20
  csslib: 0.17.0
  dash_chat: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow_dash_chat.git

  dropdown_button2: 2.3.9
  easy_date_timeline: ^0.1.1
  easy_debounce: 2.0.1
  equatable: 2.0.5
  expandable: 5.0.1
  external_path: ^1.0.3
  file_picker: 6.1.1
  firebase_auth: 4.17.7
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 7.1.7
  firebase_auth_web: 5.9.7
  firebase_core: 2.26.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 5.0.0
  firebase_core_web: 2.11.5
  firebase_messaging: 14.7.18
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 4.5.26
  firebase_messaging_web: 3.6.7
  firebase_performance: 0.9.3+16
  firebase_performance_platform_interface: 0.1.4+24
  firebase_performance_web: 0.1.4+24
  firebase_storage: any
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 5.1.11
  firebase_storage_web: 3.7.2
  flutter_animate: 4.1.1+1
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: 4.0.0
  flutter_google_places: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/ShehanYjoz/flutter_google_places.git
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: 2.0.17
  flutter_rating_bar: 4.0.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.7.0
  flutter_svg: 2.0.9
  font_awesome_flutter: 10.6.0
  from_css_color: 2.0.0
  geocoding:
  geolocator: 10.1.0
  geolocator_android: 4.4.0
  geolocator_apple: 2.3.2
  geolocator_platform_interface: 4.2.0
  geolocator_web: 2.2.0
  go_router: 12.1.3
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
  google_maps: 6.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: 2.5.0
  google_maps_flutter_platform_interface: 2.4.1
  google_maps_flutter_web: 0.5.4+2
  google_sign_in: 6.1.5
  google_sign_in_android: 6.1.20
  google_sign_in_ios: 5.6.4
  google_sign_in_platform_interface: 2.4.2
  google_sign_in_web: 0.12.1
  http: 1.2.0
  image_picker: 1.0.4
  image_picker_android: 0.8.8
  image_picker_for_web: 3.0.1
  image_picker_ios: 0.8.8+2
  image_picker_platform_interface: 2.9.1
  internet_file: 1.2.0
  intl: 0.18.1
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  json_path: 0.6.2
  lottie: 2.7.0
  map_launcher: 2.5.0+1
  mask_text_input_formatter: 2.4.0
  mime_type: 1.0.0
  package_info_plus: 4.2.0
  package_info_plus_platform_interface: 2.0.1
  page_transition: 2.1.0
  path_provider: any
  path_provider_android: 2.0.25
  path_provider_foundation: 2.2.2
  path_provider_platform_interface: 2.0.6
  pdf: ^3.8.3
  pdfx: 2.6.0
  permission_handler: ^10.4.1
  photo_view: 0.14.0
  plugin_platform_interface: 2.1.8
  pointer_interceptor: 0.10.1
  provider: 6.0.5
  rxdart: 0.27.7
  share_plus: ^6.3.4
  shared_preferences: 2.2.2
  shared_preferences_android: 2.2.1
  shared_preferences_foundation: 2.3.4
  shared_preferences_platform_interface: 2.3.1
  shared_preferences_web: 2.2.1
  sign_in_with_apple: 4.3.0
  sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface: 1.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple_web: 1.0.1
  sqflite: 2.2.6
  stream_transform: 2.1.0
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: 21.2.8
  table_calendar: 3.0.9
  text_search: 1.0.1
  timeago: 3.2.2
  universal_html: ^2.2.2
  url_launcher: 6.2.5
  url_launcher_android: 6.3.0
  url_launcher_ios: 6.2.5
  url_launcher_platform_interface: 2.3.2
  uuid: ^4.0.0
  video_player: 2.8.1
  video_player_android: 2.4.10
  video_player_avfoundation: 2.5.1
  video_player_platform_interface: 6.2.1
  video_player_web: 2.1.2
  webview_flutter: 4.7.0
  webview_flutter_android: 3.15.0
  webview_flutter_platform_interface: 2.10.0
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: 3.12.0
  webviewx_plus: 0.5.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  device_info_plus: 9.1.0
  http: 1.2.0
  pointer_interceptor: 0.10.1
  uuid: ^4.0.0
  win32: ^5.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.13.1
  flutter_lints: 3.0.0
  image: 4.0.17
  lints: 3.0.0

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  web:
    generate: true
  image_path: 'assets/images/app_launcher_icon.png'


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/audios/
    - assets/lottie_animations/
    - assets/rive_animations/
    - assets/pdfs/
  fonts:
    - family: Doctor
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/doctor.ttf
    - family: Medicine
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/medicine.ttf
    - family: Laboratory
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/laboratory.ttf
    - family: Order
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/order.ttf
    - family: Chat
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/chat.ttf
    - family: Product
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/product.ttf
    - family: Ads
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/ads.ttf
    - family: Card
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/card.ttf
    - family: Offer
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/offer.ttf
    - family: Subscription
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/subscription.ttf
    - family: Articles
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/articles.ttf
    - family: AboutUS
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/aboutUS.ttf
    - family: Faq
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/FAQ.ttf
    - family: LogOut
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/logOut.ttf
    - family: Privacy
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/privacy.ttf
    - family: Terms
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/terms.ttf
    - family: Send
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/send.ttf
    - family: Image
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/image.ttf
    - family: Hand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/hand.ttf
    - family: UpDown
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/up_down.ttf
    - family: Gender
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gender.ttf

  
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages




You need to add more logs in order understand the nature of problem. So far, I understand from the title, and that's related to win32_registry and I observed the same error yesterday.
I have solved this issue using overriding dependecy to:
win32: "5.0.0" 
win32_registry: "1.1.0"

Further more, I have cleaned up the project using and run
flutter clean
flutter run

The project ran successfully.
Let me know if you need more information. Thank you.
